# Throw exception and getting e null

Tags: android, custom-exceptions

I throw a exception with some message like:

```
public static ILSResponseEmailLookUPBO getILSUserAccounts(Resources res,
        String email) throws TripLoggerCustomException,
        TripLoggerUnexpectedErrorException {
    String resp = null;

    String lookupURL;
    try {
        lookupURL = TripLoggerConstants.ServerConstants.ILS_LOOKUP_URL
                + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        throw new TripLoggerCustomException(
                res.getString(R.string.error_try_again));
    }
    try {
        resp = ConnectionManager.getInstance().httpRequest(lookupURL,
                TripLoggerConstants.RequestMethods.GET);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals(
                res.getString(R.string.network_unreachable))
                || e.getMessage().equals(
                        res.getString(R.string.host_unresolved))) {
            throw new TripLoggerCustomException(
                    res.getString(R.string.network_not_reachable));
        } else {
            throw new TripLoggerCustomException(
                    res.getString(R.string.email_notfound_ils));
        }
    }
```

here my else part execute.
And my exception class is:

```
 public class TripLoggerCustomException extends Exception {

    private String customMessage;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TripLoggerCustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public TripLoggerCustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.customMessage = (message == null ? "" : message);
    }

    public String getCustomMessage() {
        return this.customMessage;
    }

    public void setCustomMessage(String customMessage) {
        this.customMessage = customMessage;
    }
     }
```

And here i catch this exception:

```
  private void manageLookUpActions(final String emailID) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                listILSAccounts = ILSLookupEmailBL.getILSUserAccounts(
                        getResources(), emailID);
            } catch (TripLoggerCustomException e) {
                dismissProgressBar();
                handleException(e.getMessage());
                return;
            } catch (TripLoggerUnexpectedErrorException e) {
                dismissProgressBar();
                handleException(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
}
    }.start();

}
```

but here in catch of `TripLoggerCustomException e` is `null`.why?Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe this is impossible. If the exception was null, then the system could never figure out it was of type `TripLoggerCustomException`. Do you get a NullPointer exception in this line: `handleException(e.getMessage());`. Can you try to add a global `} catch (Exception e){}` to see if it ends up there?

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie there is not occurred null pointer exception and it exactly enter in TripLoggerCustomException catch block but the issue is "e" is null in catch block of TripLoggerCustomException.

Comment: Well, if `e` really is null then `e.getMessage()` will result in a NullPointerException. I'm pretty sure that there is no way that e is null at that point.

Comment: Or do you mean that the message is null? In that case, make sure that the message you pass to the `TripLoggerCustomException` in `getILSUserAccounts()` has a correct text. You could print the content of `res.getString(R.string.error_try_again)` (or one of the other lines where you throw that exception) to your log.

Comment: I print that message that is not null but in catch block instance of "e" is null this is main issue

Comment: This is impossible. You can try to eliminate your custom exception, and throw the `UnsupportedEncodingException` and `IOException` and see what happens then. If that works correctly, then there is probably something wrong in your custom Exception (but I don't see what at a first glance).

Comment: Yes exactly  i throw TripLoggerUnexpectedErrorException and in catch block of TripLoggerUnexpectedErrorException e is not null so there is issue with TripLoggerCustomException but TripLoggerCustomException and  TripLoggerUnexpectedErrorException have same integration and this issue is so weird.

Comment: Can you post the full method of `getILSUserAccounts()`, so I can see where you throw it? Also, let the code run completely, and show me the NullPointer from your log. You WILL get a NullPointer if e is null.

Comment: More importantly, can you show the `handleException()` method. There might be an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into [multiple reports](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+catched+exception+is+null) on StackOverflow, it seems like this is not an actual issue. Multiple people have been saying that it is a problem in the combination of the Eclipse debugger and the Android Emulator. That is why you don't get a NullPointerException, which you would definitely get if `e` was null.

So this is probably not an issue you have to worry about.